# Broadcom Wifi BCM4318 [Airforce one54g] does not connect

Tags: wireless, broadcom, acer, aspire

I am hoping someone in here can help me. I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. But I have to say I really love using the Os. 
I am running Ubuntu 12.04 along side Windowns 7. Both Os are running perfect bar the wireless on Ubuntu, just not working. Network cable is fine.

My System details are Acer Aspire 5103 WLMI, AMD Turion 64x2, 120G HD, upgraded to 4G Ram with Ubuntu running along side Windows 7. Network controller is working fine, with perfect WiFi on the Windows 7 partition. But I have tried everything to get the WiFi to work on Ubuntu with no luck so far.

Below is the Network controller details.

Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 02).

I have tried everything on the [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868) reless-drivers page. 
With no joy. I have been at this three days now. All help and advice welcome! Even if it doesnt work. TRIAL and ERROR can be a great way to learn.

Regards Sean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source

sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

sudo modprobe b43
```

Comment: This is outdated. `linux-firmware-nonfree` is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Driver for this adapter can be installed by

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac bcma
sudo modprobe b43
```

You have to be connected to internet by wire to install the driver.