# cant connect to wifi on ubuntu 16.04 with a wireless card

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, internet, ndiswrapper

im a new linux user and i recently installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my 32 bit hp pavilion dv4000 laptop along with windows xp (dual boot). on windows xp, i have internet access using a wireless card, the us robotics model usr5411 and i have no issues. the card works fine, without any issue.

on ubuntu, the card wont even turn on, and so to access the internet, install or update packages and browse the internet i have to use a lan cable. only if im connected with a lan cable ill be able to do all these.

on the forum/guide page of this wireless card, there are 3 links, the first and second links are for windows, so you can install the drivers on your windows os, and the last link, is a link for the ndiswrapper wiki page, so you can install this package or app. i didnt knew what to do because there were no instructions, so i searched on google. i found a forum (linux mint IIRC), which had some steps to install the drivers using ndiswrapper

the steps were to download those exe files from the us robotics card, so i could install the drivers,
extract the exe files, install the "INF" file, and run 2 commands. one of those commands output was nothing, and the second commands output was:

```
dev64@dev64:~$ sudo ndiswrapper -m
[sudo] password for dev64: 
module configuration already contains alias directive

module configuration already contains alias directive

module configuration already contains alias directive

module configuration already contains alias directive

module configuration already contains alias directive

module configuration already contains alias directive
```

i followed every single step carefully, but no result. i did the same steps again and again, but still the same, the card wont turn on. i took a look here, but i found nothing.ive been having this issue for about a week. and i still havent found a solution to this problem. im new to linux so i dont really know a lot about linux, so i would like some help to install the drivers, so i can have internet access using the wireless card

here is some output of some commands which show information about the card/devices plugged into my laptop? im not sure

```
dev64@dev64:~$ iwconfig
enp6s7    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

```
dev64@dev64:~$ ifconfig
enp6s7    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr thisShouldBeHiddenIThink
          inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: haveToHideThis Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: thisToo Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: andThisOne Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10576 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8560 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5845302 (5.8 MB)  TX bytes:1037231 (1.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2022 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2022 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:171267 (171.2 KB)  TX bytes:171267 (171.2 KB)
```

```
dev64@dev64:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/PM/GMS/910GML Express Processor to DRAM Controller (rev 04)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller (rev 04)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML Express Graphics Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 04)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #3 (rev 04)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #4 (rev 04)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev d4)
00:1e.2 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1e.3 Modem: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Modem Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FBM (ICH6M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 04)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) IDE Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 04)
06:06.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCI1510 PC card Cardbus Controller
06:07.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter (rev 10)
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 02)
```

```
dev64@dev64:~$ ndiswrapper -l
usrmaxg : driver installed
    device (14E4:4318) present (alternate driver: ssb)
usrmaxga : driver installed
    device (14E4:4318) present (alternate driver: ssb)
```

Comment: Your question is answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339097/broadcom-wifi-bcm4318-airforce-one54g-does-not-connect).

Comment: @EhsanSoleimani alright, ill check it later and ill reply back

Comment: @EhsanSoleimani yep, i can finally connect to wifi networks, thanks!